# sonarqube multi module hierarchy on sonarqube UI dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i am using latest [sonar scanner maven plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) along with sonarqube server v6.7.1 to generate a analysis

I have multi module project, when i run analysis mvn sonar:sonar it shows root project on dashboard is there a way i can list modules are hierarchy on sonarqube dashboard ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to customize the project homepage. However, you can see your hierarchy in the project's Code page, and from there you can drill to a module homepage.